# Can I deploy an SSIS package to the file system using DTUTIL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an SSIS package named Extract.dtsx.  I want to deploy it to the file system in F:\SQL2005\MSSQL\Package\Extract.

The Package Instllation Wizard does this simply.  I only have to choose "File system deployment" and choose the path, then click next a few times and finish.  I'm having trouble figuring out if I can do the same this using DTUTIL.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.

If you have an SSIS package C:\temp\Extract.dtsx, you can deploy it to the file system in F:\SQL2005\MSSQL\Package\Extract using these commands:

```
c:\temp\md F:\sql2005\mssql\package\Extract
c:\temp\dtutil /file Extract.dtsx /Copy FILE;F:\sql2005\mssql\package\Extract\Extract.dtsx
```

The destination folder must already exist.

You can see the package in SQL Enterprise Manager by connecting to SSIS on the server, open Stored Packages > SSIS Application Packages > Extract.